# NodeJS | Wait for an operation to finish in another script

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Long story short, I would like the object exported from `myModule` to be created only after the first script is connected to the db; and then share `myObject` with any scripts that need it. Can this be done? What are the smarter alternatives to do the same things?

```js
//mainapp.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

/*application setup stuff*/

mongoose.connect(/*...*/);
```

```js
//myModule.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

class myClass {
  constructor(){
    /*db operations*/
    this.myVar = /*...*/;
  }
}

module.exports = new myClass();
```

```js
//script.js,script2.js,script3.js...

import myObject = require('./myModule');

/*...*/ = myObject.myVar;
```

Comment: You have tagged this with `express`, which means you make the connection when you start the server. Then you only run query code inside route handlers. Problem solved. (export the class, not the instance, and create an instance later)

Comment: @ChrisG But if I export the class, then I can't import the same instance into multiple scripts :\ Am I wrong?

Comment: You could use the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Export a function that creates the object if it doesn't already exist and returns it. That way all modules will use the same instance.

Comment: @ChrisG This is exactly the answer I was looking for, if you write in the form of an answer I can mark it. Do you have to recommend smarter ways to do the same thing? What I want to do is have a structure that I load from the database once, to be reused in different scripts. I know I could just avoid using a database, but I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: I looked at this again and exporting an instance should actually work. As long as its props are accessed after the instance is initialized, I don't see why it shouldn't, but I haven't tested it yet. Did you try this and encounter issues?

Comment: To be clear: accessing some prop in another script's top level won't work because you cannot await the object's populating; but accessing it in a route handler will work fine. (however with a newer node version you could do `await myObject.init();` in the top level and provided that `init()` returns a Promise that resolves when the object is populated, this should work.)

Comment: @ChrisG But if `mainapp.js` requires `script1.js` which requires `myModule.js`, scripts are not resolved when `mainapp.js` is run? This causes the constructor to be called and the queries to be executed, before the db is connected.

Comment: So don't run the queries immediately, only when necessary. Or move the connect call inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like the object exported from myModule to be created only after the first script is connected to the db

You can start the server only if the the database connection was successfully established.

```
const app = express();

mongoose.connect(/*...*/).then(() => {
      app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
      console.log(`Example app listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`),
    );
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Comment: This is what I always do, but when I start the main script all the dependent scripts / modules are executed, or am I wrong?

Comment: @nostyn Can't you export `myObject` from `script.js` and import it to other scripts without importing it from `myModule.js`? Don't know whether it would solve the issue though...

Comment: It would work, but I don't know the order in which they are called.
I am using `myObject` as a kind of personal cache: I load a block of information from the db, and I want to be able to use it in different scripts. I don't want to use redis or other libraries, I'd like to figure out how to do it myself.